# Sorting date results from a query

Tags: functions, query

I have a site I run which shows the weddings and anniversaries of some friends.

I have this running to show the users (and their anniversaries) according to what month it is:

```
 $args = array(     
'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',   
'meta_value' => 0, 
);  


 $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args ); 
 $users = $user_query->get_results();  

 foreach( $users as $user ):    
echo $user->display_name;  
 echo ' will be celebrating their anniversary on ';     
echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'anniversary_date', true );   
 endforeach;
```

---

```
function anniversary_user_query( $query ){  

 if( $query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'anniversary_date' && $query->query_vars['meta_value'] === 0 ):    
     global $wpdb;        
     $thismonth = date('m');      
     $query->query_where = "WHERE 1=1 AND ( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'anniversary_date' AND ( MONTH( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ) = $thismonth ) )";    
endif;   
return $query;
 } 
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'anniversary_user_query' );
```

The dates in my database are structured like YYYY-MM-DD.

How can I sort the dates that will appear on the page so that they are ordered from earliest in the month (by day) to latest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `query_orderby` clause to order by day of month. Add this to your `anniversary_user_query` function:

```
$query->query_orderby = "ORDER BY DAY( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ) ASC";
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks. Another quick question if anyone could help me, how could I change this code to not just pick up on a month, but a 30 day period (so someone's anniversary on jan 12 would show up starting dec 12)?